# ImportError: cannot import name 'SummaryWriter'

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, tensorboard

Can anyone help me on this error, I am trying to use allennlp models and getting the below error.

```
 from allennlp.training.metrics import Average, BooleanAccuracy, 
 CategoricalAccuracy
 File "/home/administrator/aman/venv-kbs/lib/python3.6/site- 
 packages/allennlp/training/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
 from allennlp.training.trainer import Trainer
 File "/home/administrator/aman/venv-kbs/lib/python3.6/site- 
 packages/allennlp/training/trainer.py", line 21, in <module>
 from tensorboard import SummaryWriter
 ImportError: cannot import name 'SummaryWriter'
```

Please find below the packages installed with the versions.

```
tensorboard             1.0.0a6
tensorboard-pytorch     0.7.1
tensorboardX            0.8
tensorflow              1.4.0
tensorflow-tensorboard  0.4.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `from tensorboard import SummaryWriter` to `from tensorboardX import SummaryWriter`

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this problem once. The reason is that I named the file 'tensorboard.py',so rename the python file to ensure that it does not duplicate the system name

Comment: You saved my another hour on earth! Keep posting!